# How to use rsync include and exclude to capture distributed set of files?

Tags: backup, file-transfer, rsync

I'm trying to backup a machine using rsync and after reading numerous SO QAs and the man pages, I'm still failing to understand how include/exclude precedence works so I can transfer the right set of files. Obfuscating the specific details, I'm attempting the following:

Include rescursively:

```
/home/erik/foo
/home/erik/bar
/home/erik/baz
```

Include /git rescursively, but exclude some specific subdirs, like /git/src/github.com/foo and /git/src/github.com/bar.

So far, the rsync command I think should accomplish this. It does not, and I've tried a number of variations that fail in different ways:

```
rsync -am \
  --include='*/' \
  --include='/home/erik/foo' \
  --include='/home/erik/bar' \
  --include='/home/erik/baz' \
  --include='/git' \
  --exclude='/git/bin' \
  --exclude='/git/src/github.com/foo' \
  --exclude='/git/src/github.com/bar' \
  --exclude='*' \
  / nfs.example.com:/data/pool/backup/laptop
```

Some specific questions:

- I have seen it suggested many times that the initial --include='*/ is necessary, although I'm not entirely sure why. I gather it has something to do with ensuring directories are expanded and followed(?). I also assume the final exclude is what excludes any file that doesn't match on the higher statements? Could someone elaborate on whether or not these are both necessary, and their positions are significant?
- I am unsure whether or not the directories need leading /. I have seen hints that these paths are relative to the requested transfer root of /, which would suggest it should be something like home/erik, but I have not had success with this either. Could someone expand on how this works?
- I'm unsure if a suffix / is required in the paths if I want to include the directory and all subcontents?
- Could someone elaborate on whether or not the position of the params is actually significant, i.e., the first in the list to match will be applied?
- Is there any reason I should prefer --filter='+ X' over --include? Same for exclude?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your command is quite close to a working solution. Let's break it down because I think that will answer your specific questions too.

- `rsync -am` - Also copy obvious file metadata attributes (permissions, ownership, times); don't create empty directories on the destination
- `--include='*/'` - Include all directories (the trailing `/` matches only directories)
- `--include='/home/erik/foo'` - Include this path (`foo` might be a file or a directory; we can't tell)
- `--include='/home/erik/bar'` - Likewise for `bar`
- `--include='/home/erik/baz'` - And `baz`
- `--include='/git'` - Include the top-most `git` (the leading `/` binds to the top of the source tree; we can't tell from the parameter if `git` is a file or a directory)
- `--exclude='/git/bin'` - Exclude the file or directory `bin` (and if it's a directory, implicitly everything under it too), which is in the top-most `git` directory
- `--exclude='/git/src/github.com/foo'` - Exclude `foo` as for `/git/bin` above
- `--exclude='/git/src/github.com/bar'` - and `bar` too
- `--exclude='*'` - Exclude all files or directories that we haven't already explicitly included
- `/ nfs.example.com:/data/pool/backup/laptop` - Copy from `/` to a path on the NFS server

The first thing to remember is that actions are processed left to right (first to last), and the first match wins. This means that all your `include` statements will override the `exclude` ones.

I'd add the `-v` flag (`--verbose`) so I could see some of what was going on, and the `-n` flag for testing (`--dry-run`). Immediately you can see that you haven't included any files, other than possibly `erik`'s `foo`, `bar` and `baz`:

```
rsync --dry-run --verbose --archive --prune-empty-dirs …
```

The `**` and `***` wildcards are going to be useful here (`**` includes all files and directories underneath the current point; the `***` also applies to the current point itself):

```
--include='/home/erik/foo/***'
--include='/home/erik/bar/***'
--include='/home/erik/baz/***'
```

Exclude parts of the `git` tree, and all associated files/directories underneath

```
--exclude='/git/bin/***'
--exclude='/git/src/github.com/foo/***'
--exclude='/git/src/github.com/bar/***'
```

Now include (what's left of) `git`

```
--include='/git/***'
```

Almost there. To find directories and files other than at the top level we have to search through all the directories, so let's include those and then use `-prune-empty-dirs` to discard the empty ones

```
--include='*/'
```

Finally, we can exclude everything else

```
--exclude='*'
```

The final command is therefore

```
rsync --dry-run --verbose --archive --prune-empty-dirs \
  --include='/home/erik/foo/***' \
  --include='/home/erik/bar/***' \
  --include='/home/erik/baz/***' \
  --exclude='/git/bin/***' \
  --exclude='/git/src/github.com/foo/***' \
  --exclude='/git/src/github.com/bar/***' \
  --include='/git/***' \
  --include='*/' \
  --exclude='*' \
  / nfs.example.com:/data/pool/backup/laptop
```

Comment: Tremendously helpful answer, thank you very much. I will give this a try as soon as I'm at my machine and report back!

Comment: That worked like a charm, the piece I was missing was indeed the wildcards:

```
The ** and *** wildcards are going to be useful here (** includes all files and directories underneath the current point; the *** also applies to the current point itself):
```